# Creating a simple Iteratee gives type error ?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, read-eval-print-loop, fold, loops

I'm trying to create a simple Iteratee using Play2 on the REPL based on [this](http://mandubian.com/2012/08/27/understanding-play2-iteratees-for-normal-humans/). But I get a `missing parameters` error. But if I provide a type parameter for `ele` it works. Can someone explain this ?

```
scala> import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val i = Iteratee.fold(0){ ( acc, ele ) => acc + ele }
<console>:15: error: missing parameter type
       val i = Iteratee.fold(0){ ( acc, ele ) => acc + ele }
                                         ^
scala> val i = Iteratee.fold(0){ ( acc, ele:Int ) => acc + ele }
i: play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Int,Int] = play.api.libs.iteratee.ContIteratee@3feaaa9b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala's type inference isn't smart enough to say "oh, you wrote `acc + ele` and I know that `acc` is an integer, so `ele` must also be an integer".

In context you often won't need the extra type annotation. For example, this compiles just fine:

```
Enumerator(1, 2, 3).run(Iteratee.fold(0) { (acc, ele) => acc + ele })
```

Or this:

```
val i: Iteratee[Int, Int] = Iteratee.fold(0) { (acc, ele) => acc + ele }
```

But without some extra context you're just going to have to provide that `: Int`.